# Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306 Docker

Tags: mysql, nodejs, docker

Hola amigos tengo un error en docker mi server no se lgora conectar con la BD.
servidor: nodejs
bd: mysql

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:16

WORKDIR /index

COPY package.json .
RUN npm install

EXPOSE 3000

#CMD ["npm", "start"]

CMD /wait-for-it.sh db:3306 -- npm start

COPY . .
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.8"

networks:
  app-tier:
    driver: bridge

services:
  db:
    image: mysql
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    restart: always
    expose:
      - "3306"
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    networks:
      - app-tier
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: bdprueba
      MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: ok
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_USER: admin
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: bdprueba
      MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: '%'
  backend:
    depends_on:
      - db
    build: .
    command: bash -c 'while !</dev/tcp/db/3306; do sleep 1; done; npm start'
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    networks:
      - app-tier
```

.env

```
NODE_ENV=development
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_USER=admin
DB_PASSWORD=dbprueba
DB_NAME=dbprueba
DB_CONNCETION=mysql


PORT=3001
```

Comment: Estás tratando de usar localhost:3306 para conectarte a la base de datos. Al usar docker deberías usar el nombre de tu servicio como “dominio”. En este caso db:3306.

Comment: osea en el .env cambio localhost por 3306

Comment: No, el puerto está bien. En lugar de usar localhost deberías usar `db`

Comment: Por cierto en tu `.env`. Hay un typo. `DB_CONNCETION` debería ser `DB_CONNECTION`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El error está en querer usar `localhost` como el host de la base de datos.
Al usar Docker debes usar el nombre de tu servicio para definir la conexión.

```
NODE_ENV=development
DB_HOST=db
DB_USER=admin
DB_PASSWORD=dbprueba
DB_NAME=dbprueba
DB_CONNECTION=mysql // aquí había un typo


PORT=3001
```

En este caso en lugar de usar `localhost` como `DB_HOST` debes usar el nombre de tu servicio, el cual es `db`

Comment: parent: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306

      at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1157:16) {

    errno: -111,

    code: 'ECONNREFUSED',

    syscall: 'connect',

    address: '127.0.0.1',

    port: 3306,

    fatal: true

  }, Me sigue saliendo este error, pero algo que note es que la BD se incia primero antes que el servidor

Comment: Que se inicie primero la BD esta bien. Ya que especificas en tu Docker-compose que tú backend depende del servicio de bd.

Comment: Otro error es que las credenciales que muestras en tu docker-compose no coinciden con las que aparecen en tu .env. En uno aparecen como `bdprueba` y en otros `dbprueba`

Comment: Perdon lo dije al contrario se termina de ejecutar la bd despues de que se termina el servidor o sea el servidor no alcanza a conectar cuando la bd ya se crea

Comment: OK ya encontre el error, resulta que se ejcutaba la carpeta dir y no la src